# Bash script to add multiple lines to a file in alphabetical order

Tags: bash, sed

I have an html document which I want to edit from a bash script. The hmtl file has a table of entries formatted like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="XXXX-1.example.com">XXXX</a></td>
        <td><a href="XXXX-2.example.com">XXXX</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="YYYY-1.example.com">YYYY</a></td>
        <td><a href="YYYY-2.example.com">YYYY</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with each `<tr>` containing two `<td>`s with links to different versions of each thing.

What I need to do, from a bash script, add a new `<tr>` block into the table, in the correct alphabetical order according to whatever XXXX is.

I already have a larger script that adds entries to a bunch of other files via sed commands, but this file needs to be in alphabetical order, and I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Why are you tied to bash exactly? It sounds like a pain in the ass way to do it.

Comment: This would be relatively simple with a tool that is designed to monkey with a DOM or reasonable with a tool that is designed to parse XML or HTML. bash isn't that tool though. Trying to make it that tool is going to lead to pain as the scope of this script grows.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` doesn't understand html. Use an html-aware tool, for example [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open :F html file.html ;
my $new = "JJJJ" ;
my $after = //table/tr[xsh:strmax($new, preceding-sibling::tr/td/a) = $new][last()] ;

my $tr := insert element tr before $after ;
insert chunk {"
    <td><a href='$new-1.example.com'>$new</a></td>
    <td><a href='$new-2.example.com'>$new</a></td>
"} into $tr ;
```

Note the XPath that locates the `tr` after which the new one should be inserted: it's the last `tr` such that a max string from all its preceding sibling `tr`'s plus the new string is equal to the new string. The following `tr` will have the string greater than the new one, so it would change the maxstr. (The code doesn't handle the case when the new string should come first, in such a case, $after would be empty).